# NPM recursive Unmet peer dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, npm

I'm trying to upgrade my @ionic-native/core so I can install an OIDC client.
No matter what commands I tried I am returned an error:

> UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @ionic-native/core@4.5.2

I've tried:

```
npm update @ionic-native/core@4.5.2 --save

npm update @ionic-native/core@latest --save

npm uninstall @ionic-native/core --save
npm install @ionic-native/core --save
```

All of these return that same error, which is weird because how can @ionic-native/core@4.5.2 be a dependency of itself?

Comment: Try delete package-lock.json and update/install again?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else encounters this issue.  Some how when I was running one of the NPM Commands a duplicate dependency was added to my package.Json for @ionic-native/core@4.5.2 with an older version.

Once I removed the duplicate line from the package.Json everything started to work fine again